# PVST + MST + RSTP network. Possible to make it work?

Tags: cisco, spanning-tree, networking, redundancy, pvst

I have got a network (around 100 switches) which looks like this:

Cisco 2960 - can do PVST, RSTP, MST

MRV mr2228-s2c - can do STA, MSTP

HP 1810 - can do RSTP, STP

[image: IMAGE HERE]

Two main Ciscos are linked with two cables and use PVST with each other.

Lets say 40 switches (Mrv xy) use MST. Mrv 1 is connected to main Cisco 1. Last Mrv is connected to main Cisco 2.

To make it more fun, I have 30 HP xy and those use RSTP. First HP is connected to main Cisco 1 with BPDU GUARD here, because it kept crashing and this was only thing that helped. Last HP is connected to smaller Cisco 1 and it ends at smaller Cisco 5.

**We are here right now and everything works.**

What I need to do right now is to connect smaller Cisco 5 to main Cisco 2 because I need redundancy.
I expect nothing less then unrepairable hell when those two meet.

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: The number of workable configurations of STP gets smaller and smaller as topologies become more complex while the number of configurations that will result in a smoking crater grows larger and larger.  While there may be a way to make this work it's going to be brittle at best and will likely not survive the next person who adds or removes a link.  Choose one common protocol and deploy it over a consistent topology with deterministic priority values throughout.

Comment: Choosing one common protocol would be ideal. Unfortunately those switches don't support the same protocol and we are nowhere near being able to buy 80 switches to change the older ones.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: @RonMaupin We have yet to solve it. No answer was good enough - I will add one if we manage to make it work for possible future networkers.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, you should stick to one spanning-tree protocol or only use those that interact well (e.g. MSTP and RSTP). Given the 1810 can only run RSTP that would be your choice. The downside of RSTP is that you can't spread VLANs across redundant links.

It's possible to mix RPVST and RSTP but it's not always easy and won't work when chaining mixed switches like in your sketch.

Chaining should generally be avoided. Consider connecting all edge swichtes to your core/main ones. If there aren't enough port you need an [aggregation layer](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/switches/nexus-7000-series-switches/white-paper-c11-737022.pdf) of switches in between.

Before you close the loop as intended you need to make sure that there is a single spanning tree (or multiple overlapping with RPVST) in your structure. If any switch doesn't correctly participate in the tree the loop will not be detected, resulting in a broadcast storm. If the Cisco5 switch shows main1 or main2 (depending on their priority) as root bridge all should be well.

Comment: I would gladly avoid chaining, unfortunately all the switches support different spanning-tree protocols so "make sure that there is a single spanning tree (...) in your structure" is not possible.

Comment: The 2960 can do RSTP or MSTP but probably default to RPVST - set all switches to MSTP or RSTP and you've got a single tree. If chaining cannot be prevented you might want to shorten the chains or add redundant shortcuts within each cluster (e.g. connect HP1 to HP30). As it is, if HP1 or one of its links fails you've got 34 offline switches. Even with the redundancy loop the topology isn't exactly ideal.